# Github clone remote branch error not found

Tags: git-clone

I'm trying to clone openFrameworks on my windows 8 based computer and I'm using this command

```
git clone -b develop git://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks.git
```

This is the error I get:

```
fatal: Remote branch developed not found in upstream origin.
```

Any ideas? Because when I looked up the git from the github.com site it seems to be there.

Answer (score 2):

On the site: https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks

There is a button called branch:master.  It shows you which branches are available and develop is not one of them.  More than likely you'll just want to pull from the master branch

```
git clone https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks.git
```