# Cloning a branch : Remote branch branch-99 not found in upstream origin

Tags: git, github, git-clone

How can I clone a branch from git with a specific Branch name?

I have a branch named `branch-99` and my user name is `Istiak`.

I try to clone my branch like:

```
git clone -b branch-99 git@github.istiak/admin.git
```

I am receiving this error.

> fatal: Remote branch branch-99 not found in upstream origin

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you check that your branch is available on the remote system? That was likely the problem solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815127/github-clone-remote-brach-error-not-found .

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`branch-99` does not exist on the remote repository.  You probably misspelled the branch name or the repository.

To check which branches exist, use [`ls-remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote.html). You can use it on the remote...

```
git ls-remote --heads origin
```

Or if you haven't already cloned the repository, on a URL.

```
git ls-remote --heads git@github.com:Christoffer/admin.git
```

You'll get the commit IDs and branch names, but they'll be full references like `refs/heads/<branch>`.

```
8c2ac78ceba9c5265daeab1519b84664127c0e7d    refs/heads/fix/that
6bc88ec7c9c7ce680f8d69ced2e09f18c1747393    refs/heads/master
83f062226716bb9cebf10779834db1ace5578c50    refs/heads/branch-42
```

See [`gitrevisions`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#_specifying_revisions) for more.

---

To be clear, `git clone -b branch-99 git@github.com:Christoffer/admin.git` clones the entire repository. It just checks out `branch-99` rather than `master`. It's the same as...

```
git clone git@github.com:Christoffer/admin.git
git checkout branch-99
```

That bit of syntax sugar isn't worth the bother. I guess it might save you a tiny bit of time not having to checkout master.

If you want to clone just the history of one branch to save some network and disk space use `--single-branch`.

```
git clone --single-branch -b branch-99 git@github.com:Christoffer/admin.git
```

However it's usually not worth the trouble. Git is very disk and network efficient. And the whole history of that branch has to be cloned which usually includes most of the repository anyway.

Comment: Yes, if the specified branch is not available for the git repository, this error will be thrown.

Comment: had the same issue was spelling the branch wrong, thanks!

Comment: For me it was a Space issue.
Somehow It was giving me an extra Space in the name.

Answer (score 3):

```
git clone git@github.com:Christoffer/admin.git
git checkout branch-99
```

Comment: This won't help if `branch-99` doesn't exist.

Comment: when i use git clone git@github.com:Christoffer/admin.git it clone my entire master not the branch-99

Comment: For me it was a Space issue.
Somehow It was giving me an extra Space in the name.