# listing and switching /checkout to remote branch error

Tags: git, remote-branch

git ls-remote origin lists all the remote with their commit IDs,

```
xxxx41   refs/heads/ABC
xxxx92   refs/heads/dummy_xyz
xxxx32   refs/heads/Feature/ABC
xxxx77   refs/heads/Feature/ABC-mgc
```

now when i checkout to any of the branch i get an error

```
error: pathspec "/Feature/ABC" or "/Feature/ABC-mgc" did not match any files known to git
```

i followed some questions on stack [Remote branch not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32578224/cloning-a-branch-remote-branch-branch-99-not-found-in-upstream-origin)

@schwern did wonderful explanation however i could not able to checkout.

Comment: In the provided answer, if fetch doesn't help, can you show your `checkout` command? Maybe you're accidentally prefixing the branch name with the `/` character...

Comment: What does `git branch --all` show? If `remotes/origin/Feature/ABC` is not listed, then [Yedidya Rashi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75111362/23118) is the solution.

Comment: @hlovdal git branch --all shows only two branches,    "develop, remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/develop & remotes/origin/develop

Answer (score 1):

Try to fetch the branches first:

```
git fetch
git checkout {the branch that you want}
```

Comment: Thanks Rashi,  yes i tried git tech, git fetch -all,  also tried with --depth=1 but nothing worked